# AsyncHttpResponseHandler issue: get value before completion of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a String variable in main class `private String gameEnabled = "0";` , how can I update the variable immediately inside my `AsyncHttpResponseHandler` to avoid getting value before completion of AsyncTask?

My `AsyncHttpResponseHandler`:

```
try {
        APICaller.App_Game_Enabled(getApplicationContext(), new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String error) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                try {

                    JSONArray json_Response = APICaller.XMLtoJsonArray(response);

                    if (json_Response.length() > 0) {
                        JSONObject dataNode = json_Response.getJSONObject(0);
                        gameEnabled = dataNode.getString("result");
                    } else {
                        //showAlert(getResources().getString(R.string.ShowAlert_Alert), getResources().getString(R.string.ShowAlert_CreatorAccess));
                    }
                    // Progress_Hide();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    //finish();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Expected to update `gameEnabled` to "1" after this code but I always get the default "0". How can I deal with this if I need to follow below conditions? Thanks in advanced.

- Use AsyncHttpResponseHandler
- Update `gameEnabled` inside the AsyncHttpResponseHandler class and use it outside the class